# C++ void function trying to return an int?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a header file in which a void function is declared. In the source file I have written implementation for this function. Upon compiling the project I receive an error indicating that my implementation does not match a prototype in the header.

The code in the header file (Dictionary.h) appears as:

```
void spellCheck(ifstream checkFile, string fileName, std::ostream &out);
```

The code in the source file (Dictionary.cpp) appears as:

```
Dictionary::spellCheck(ifstream checkFile, string fileName, std::ostream &out){
    _report.setFileName(fileName);
    string end = "\n";
    int words = 0;
    int wrong = 0;
    string word;
    char currChar;
    while(checkFile >> word){
        currChar = checkFile.get();
        while(currChar != "\\s" && currChar == "\\w"){
            word += currChar;
            currChar = checkFile.get();
        }
        out << word << end;
        word.clear();
    }
    /*
    _report.setWordsRead(words);
    _report.setWordsWrong(wrong);
    _report.printReport();
    */
}
```

Is there anything here that might indicate that I have tried to return an integer value?

The exact error is:

```
Dictionary.cpp:31:1: error: prototype for 'int Dictionary::spellCheck(std::ifstream, std::string, std::ostream&)' does not match any in class 'Dictionary'
Dictionary::spellCheck(ifstream checkFile, string fileName, std::ostream &out){
^
In file included from Dictionary.cpp:8:0:
Dictionary.h:21:10: error: candidate is: void Dictionary::spellCheck(std::ifstream, std::string, std::ostream&)
 void spellCheck(ifstream checkFile, string fileName, std::ostream &out);
      ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `void` here:

```
Dictionary::spellCheck(ifstream checkFile, string fileName, std::ostream &out){
```

so you are implicitly defining the function as returning `int`.

It should be:

```
void Dictionary::spellCheck(ifstream checkFile, string fileName, std::ostream &out){
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I completely missed that!

Comment: If this solved your question mark it as accepted, benefits both you and the question's answerer